# Override function in interface

Tags: c#, class, interface, overriding, multiple-inheritance

How to override functions with the same name and signature which are in two different interfaces, in a class that is inheriting both interfaces.
Is it possible ?

Note: This was an interview question I was asked.

Example:

```
interface example1
{
    int add(int a, int b);
}

interface example2
{
    int add(int a, int b);
}


public class cls : example1, example2
{
    public int add(int a, int b)
    {

        int c = a + b;
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code they provided you is a bit lacking, it should have followed existing naming conventions for classes, interfaces and methods. That is the reason that in my answer I am sticking to the official documentation sample code on that topic.

Comment: **Don't scream**. And use proper naming conventions. Interfaces are just specifications, you don't inherit them, you implement them. That's not nit-picking. In case of conflict you have to specify which method in your code implements which interface method

Comment: `This was an interview question I was asked.` things like this are covered in all tutorials, courses, tests and part of certification tests. You should perhaps try the practice tests in eg Pluralsight before applying to interviews. You can get free access to Pluralsight's courses for several months through Microsoft's (also free) Visual Studio Dev Essentials program. Pluralsight authors are the best known book and blog authors in the .NET space. It's where all those "free" courses steal their content from

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several options when we have two or more interfaces with the same methods:

We can use [explicit interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) implementation:

```
public class cls : example1, example2 {
  // note abscence of "public", the method efficiently private
  int example1.add(int a, int b) => a + b;

   // note abscence of "public", the method efficiently private
  int example2.add(int a, int b) => Math.Abs(a) + Math.Abs(b);
}
```

The call wants *cast* to the required interface:

```
var demo = new cls();

Console.Write($"{((example1)demo).add(2, -3)} : {((example2)demo).add(2, -3)}");
```

If we have some method `add` as a default behaviour (say `example1`), we can use explicit interface implementation for `example2` only:

```
public class cls : example1, example2 {
  public int add(int a, int b) => a + b;

  int example2.add(int a, int b) => Math.Abs(a) + Math.Abs(b);
}
```

And now the call wants cast in case of `example2` only:

```
var demo = new cls();

Console.Write($"{demo.add(2, -3)} : {((example2)demo).add(2, -3)}");
```

Finally, if *both* interfaces share the same method:

```
public class cls : example1, example2 {
  // Both interfaces example1 and example2 share the same method
  public int add(int a, int b) => a + b;
}
```

Comment: You should probably not use the OP's naming convention as it will further confuse them and everyone else that encounters this in the future. The OP needs to understand there's no inheritance involved here.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: you absolutely right: the names should be at least capitalised; however, since it's an interview question with given names I decided to preserve them.

Comment: If I encountered and interview with that naming I would consider opting out of that position. Having a stablised naming convention among all the teams is very important.

Comment: @Cleptus: may be it's a kind of *provocation*,  candidate is expected to blame such a naming convention and propose better names.